# Можно ли включить подсказки кода в Visual Studio Code для сторонних библиотек?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Здравствуйте.

Использую библиотеку `svg.js` и её плагины. При наборе кода `VSCode` не выдаёт подсказки, а на официальной странице [svg.js](http://svgjs.com/) очень маленькая документация, в которой описаны не все методы и функции.

Можно ли каким-то образом сделать так, чтобы `VSCode` давал подсказки по коду?

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/geo.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="drawing"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/svgScripts/svg/svg.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/svgScripts/svgDraggable/svg.draggable.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/svgScripts/svgDraw/svg.draw.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/svgScripts/svgResize/svg.resize.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/svgScripts/svgSelect/svg.select.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/geo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript (geo.js)

```
SVG.on(document, 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    if (SVG.supported) {
        var draw = SVG('drawing');

        draw. //после точки должны появиться подсказки

    } else {
        alert('SVG not supported');
    }
});
```

Comment: эмм, так вот же [types](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/blob/master/svg.js.d.ts) уточните пожалуйста 1. как вы устанавливаете библиотеку (версия, содержание package.json) 2. пишите на js или ts 3. пример кода

Comment: @qwabra Пишу на js. package.json взял на GitHub в их репозитории. package.json находится в той же папке, что и svg.js. Самый простой пример кода: `var draw = SVG('drawing'); draw. после точки, VS Code должна предлагать варианты`.

Comment: зря метки поменяли, то что вам нужно - файлы `*.d.ts` это часть `typescript` `@types` но обо всём подробнее завтра.

Comment: @qwabra Понял, буду Вас ждать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ответ разделён на две части:

1. Можно ли включить подсказки кода в VSCode для сторонних библиотек?
2. Можно ли включить подсказки кода в VSCode для **svg.js**
3. Разбор svg.js

## 1. Можно ли включить подсказки кода в VSCode для сторонних библиотек?

да, можно.
если вам повезло - устанавливаете из npm пакет и всё.
если не повезло - ищите `*.d.ts`

**npm**

- https://www.npmjs.com/
- https://www.npmjs.com/~types

**definitelytyped**

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript
- http://definitelytyped.org/
- https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/
- https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

то, что вам нужно гуглится так `@types имя_библиотеки`
ещё можно посмотреть тут http://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/

например для **nodejs** - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node
установка происходит командой `npm install --save @types/node` (!обратите внимание на версию типов и программы, могут отличаться)
после выполнения этой команды, скачиваются файлы содержащие только описание библиотеки, только **типы**, которые хранятся в файле с расширением `*.d.ts`

с недавнего времени, некоторые библиотеки при установке из npm уже содержат types и в этом случае не требуется выполнение `npm install --save @types`

## 2. Можно ли включить подсказки кода в VSCode для **svg.js**

- http://svgjs.com/
- https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js
- https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/blob/master/svg.js.d.ts

> Использую библиотеку svg.js

имеет `.d.ts` не всё описано

> и её плагины

неизвестно имеют ли `.d.ts` сомнительно

## 3. Разбор svg.js

далее пример, взят отсюда:

- http://svgjs.com/#go-crazy-with-animations
- http://jsfiddle.net/wout/7wL1uv8n/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=7wL1uv8n

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input[type=text]')
var draw = SVG('drawing').viewbox(0, 0, 300, 140)
var text = draw.text(function(add) {
 add.tspan( input.value )
})

text
 .path('M10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80')
 .animate(1000, '<>')
 .plot('M10 80 C 40 150, 65 150, 95 80 S 150 10, 180 80')
 .loop(true, true)

input.addEventListener('keyup', updateText(text))

function updateText(textPath) {
 return function() {
  textPath.tspan(this.value)
 }    
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata');
#drawing {
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
}
tspan {
 fill: #e5e5e5;
 stroke: #f06;
 stroke-width: 0.85;
  font-family: 'Inconsolata';
}
input[type=text] {
 width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Inconsolata';
  font-size: 14px;
  outline: none;
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/ceaf24d5/dist/svg.min.js">
/*! svg.js v2.4.0 MIT*/
</script>
<input type="text" value="Dragon----- - - - ->" placeholder="Type text here...">
<div id="drawing"></div>
```

---

### разбор примера

создаём папку `test`
переходим в неё
создаём файл `package.json` следующего содержания:

```
{
    "author": "qwa",
    "description": "",
    "tags": [],
    "name": "svg.js",
    "private": true,
    "main": "",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "svg.js": "2.4.0" //<- библиотека такой же версии как в примере
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "reload": "2.2.2" //<- веб сервер для разработки
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "reload"
    }
}
```

выполнием `npm install`
создаётся директория `node_modules` примерно такого содержания:

```
node_modules
├── ...
├── svg.js
│   ├── bench
│   ├── dist
│   │   ├── svg.js     <-- скомпилированный файл библиотеки
│   │   └── svg.min.js
│   ├── spec
│   ├── src            <-- исходики библиотеки
│   ├── ...
│   └──svg.js.d.ts     <-- файл описания библиотеки
├── ...
└── ...
```

**создаём и заполняем**

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!--
        и что мы видим
        это не работает!
    -->
    <!-- <script src="/node_modules/svg.js/dist/svg.js"></script> -->

    <!-- и это тоже -->
    <!-- <script src="/node_modules/svg.js/dist/svg.min.js"></script> -->

    <!-- зато это работает, чудеса, да и только -->
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/ceaf24d5/dist/svg.min.js">
        /*! svg.js v2.4.0 MIT*/
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <input type="text" value="Dragon----- - - - ->" placeholder="Type text here...">
    <div id="drawing"></div>
    <script src="/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

index.css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata');
#drawing {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
tspan {
    fill: #e5e5e5;
    stroke: #f06;
    stroke-width: 0.85;
    font-family: 'Inconsolata';
}
input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Inconsolata';
    font-size: 14px;
    outline: none;
    color: #666;
}
```

index.js

```
//#region плохих советов
/// <reference path="./node_modules/svg.js/svg.js.d.ts" />

if(!SVG){//hack for intellisense
    var SVG = svgjs
}
//#endregion плохих советов

var input = document.querySelector('input[type=text]')
var draw = SVG('drawing').viewbox(0, 0, 300, 140)
var text = draw.text(function(add) {
    add.tspan( input.value )
})

text
    .path('M10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80')
    .animate(1000, '<>')
    .plot('M10 80 C 40 150, 65 150, 95 80 S 150 10, 180 80')
    .loop(true, true)

input.addEventListener('keyup', updateText(text))

function updateText(textPath) {
    return function() {
        textPath.tspan(this.value)
    }
}
```

выполняем `npm start`
смотрим http://127.0.0.1:8080/

---

найденные с ходу ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как мы видим, в функцию `viewbox` передано 4 элемента, в то время как в types принимается всего один

https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/blob/ceaf24d5/svg.js.d.ts#L143

далее, в чэйнинге

```
text
    .path()
    .animate()
    .plot()
    .loop()
```

функция `animate` возвращает объект `Animation` из которого вызывается функция `plot`
в то время как в types она отсутствует
https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/blob/ceaf24d5/svg.js.d.ts#L930

---

**резюмируя**

у вас есть два пути:

1. использовать как есть/ писать на гитхаб/ допиливать типы
2. создать новый вопрос 'какие библиотеки для svg поддерживаются typescript' с меткой svg typescript

Comment: Спасибо большое за содержательный ответ! К счастью, мне повезло, и я нашел npm пакеты для svg.js и плагинов к нему

Comment: текст после картинки повествует о найденных мной ошибках в файле типов ` "svg.js": "2.4.0"`. а так, рад за вас. для jq тоже есть типы, вроде

Comment: Нет, к сожалению не работает даже с nmp пакетами. VS Code ничего не подсказывает. Очень жаль, очень много плагинов для этой библиотеки, которые мне были нужны. Пойду создавать новый вопрос

Comment: @Klimbo, если вы работаете с картами, возможно вам нужны библиотеки для карт а не svg ..

Comment: Я не работаю с картами. Библиотека нужна для след. задачи: Пользователь зажимает ЛКМ, отводит мышь, за мышью рисуется окружность, чтобы окружность перестала следовать за курсором, пользователь отпускает ЛКМ. Затем пользователь может навести мышь на дугу окружности и зажать ЛКМ, если он будет двигать мышь, то центр окружности должен оставаться на месте, а радиус должен изменяться (расстояние от центра до курсора). И такую процедуру пользователь может повторять неограниченное кол-во раз.